# How can I detect that my network interface is connected to internet programmatically using C++?

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a software solution which contains a C++ library. The library deals with connectivity related things. But I am stuck on a point. I need to deal with all the connected network interface. To optimize the software solution a bit I have decided I will only work with the interfaces which are connected to the internet. That's why I need to determine whether the interface is connected to internet or not. I have searched on the web for simple solutions that will work on all the platforms. But I haven't found so. Now I am seeking help to find a comprehensive solution that will work on all platform such as iOS, Windows, Android, Linux, and MAC. Any kind of suggestion and advice will be appreciated in this regard.

Comment: There's no standard c++ way of doing this. You'll have to address it at platform level.

Comment: Actually I need to find a solution which deals with interface IP. Currently I found a way which only checks whether my PC has internet connection or not.

Comment: Comprehensive solution: choose a website, create a connection on the tested interface, and get data from your website. Smilar to validating e-mail addresses, the best way to provide a "go/no-go" flag for a network interface, is to actually use it and see.

Comment: "is connected" suggests a boolean state which is unrealistic. Is a system behind a NAT or firewall connected to the Internet? What about IPv4/6 ? The real question is of course, "is it connected in a way that's compatible with my needs"? Only one way to find that out.

Comment: @MSalters which way?

Comment: @NaseefUrRahman: To do what utnapistim said - attempt to create a real connection to an external server and see if it succeeds or fails.  There are two many possible connectivity options to query an interface for a simple "connected" status. Think of an interface that is connected to a NAT, but the NAT is not connected to the Internet. The interface is still "connected".

Comment: In addition to @RemyLebeau answer, if you are looking for a library that works on a variety of platforms then [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial) is probably your best bet as that supports all platforms you listed.

Comment: @graham.reeds I have used the library before. But I think it is too much large for this task. The binary size will significantly increase.

Comment: It is **operating-system specific** since standard C++11 or C++14 does not know about sockets

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was done by the suggestion given by Remy Lebeau. I am checking TCP connection with google, amazon and twitter. Firstly I am resolving the address and collecting only the IPv4 addresses. After that I am trying to connect with all of these addresses sequentially. If any of them succeeds then I am saying it is connected with internet and returning from the function without trying any other addresses from the collected list.

If TCP connection with all the addresses fails, then I am saying that internet connection is unavailable.

This solution works for me in almost all cases.

Comment: This will fail mizerably in any network that does the captive portal thingy.

Comment: Do you have any better suggestion for me?